# jQgrid Edit command not rendering in mvc action method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am trying to create a jQGrid in my MVC 4 application but there is in JQGrid Edit Action not working. My code is below.

**.cshtml**

```
<table id="jQGridDemo">
</table>
<div id="jQGridDemoPager">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
    url: '/Home/FillGrid/',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Description', 'Created'],
    colModel: [{ name: 'Id', Index: 'Id', width: 100, align: 'left' },
               { name: 'Name', Index: 'Name', width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true },
               { name: 'Description', Index: 'Description', width: 400, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true },
               { name: 'Created', Index: 'Created', width: 100, align: 'left' }],
    rowNum: 10,
    mtype: 'GET',
    loadonce: true,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'desc',
    caption: "List Employee Details",
    editurl: '@Url.Action("Update", "Home")',        
    deleteurl: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Home")', 
});

$('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jQGridDemoPager',
           {
               edit: true,
               add: true,
               del: true,
               search: true,
               searchtext: "Search",
               addtext: "Add",
               edittext: "Edit",
               deltext: "Delete"
           },
           {//EDIT
               url: '@Url.Action("Update", "Home")',
               width: 400,
           },
           {
               width: 400,
               //color: Red
           },
           {//DELETE
               url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Home")',
           },
           {//SEARCH
               closeOnEscape: true
           }
    );

  </script>
```

**Action**

```
    public ActionResult FillGrid(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        List<Master> models = new List<Master>();

        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pagesize = rows;
        int totalrecords = 0;
        int totalpages = 0;

        using (var db = new jQGridDemoEntities())
        {
            totalrecords = db.Masters.Count();
            totalpages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalrecords / (float)pagesize);

            models = db.Masters.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip(pageIndex * pagesize).Take(pagesize).ToList();
        }

        var jsondata = new
        {
            total = totalpages,
            page,
            records = totalrecords,
            rows = (
            from master in models
            select new
            {
                i = master.Id,
                cell = new string[] { master.Id.ToString(), master.Name.ToString(), master.Description.ToString(), master.Created.ToString() }
            }).ToArray()
        };

        return Json(jsondata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(string Name, string Description)
    {
        int ret = 2;
        return Json(ret);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
    {
        int ret = 2;
        return Json(ret);
    }
```

I already specify the editurl and deleteurl in the jQgrid initilize section.

For example I need to update Name and Description field in the Edit popup.

The Update action is fired in the Edit popup but the inside of the submit action not working.

There is any configuration needed to bind fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You current code contains some errors. The first one in the lines

```
from master in models
select new
{
    i = master.Id,
    cell = new string[] { master.Id.ToString(), ... }
}
```

You assign `i` property (see `i = master.Id`) instead of usage `id` name (`id = master.Id`). The name of `id` used in the input data can be changed assigning `id` property of `jsonReader` option (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data)). Default value is `id: "id"`. To use `i` instead of `id` one could use `jsonReader: { id: "i" }` option.

One more good way to specify `id` used for rows: usage of `key: true` property for definition of "Id" column. By the way if you want to display `id` of the row to the user and you use `key: true` property then you don't need to send `master.Id` twice (once as `id = master.Id` and one more time as `cell = new string[] { master.Id.ToString(), ... }`). Instead of that you can use something like

```
return Json((
    from master in models
    select new [] {
        master.Id.ToString(),
        master.Name,
        master.Description,
        master.Created.ToString()
    }
).ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In the case the data returned from `FillGrid` will be array or items directly. You don't need set `total`, `page` and `records` properties inside of returned data because you use `loadonce: true` and all the properties will be just ignored by jqGrid.

In the same way `prmNames` option can be used to rename the default `id` name use for Add/Edit and Delete operation to another name.

The next problem. You use `sortname: 'id'`, but there are only column with `name: 'Id'`. So you should change `sortname: 'id'` to `sortname: 'Id'`. The delete action uses `int Id`. So you can use `prmNames: { id: "Id" }` option or to rename `int Id` to `int id`. The option will be used in Add/Edit cation too. So you should add `int Id` to `int id` to `Update` action depend on whether you use `prmNames: { id: "Id" }` option or not.

Comment: Hi @Oleg,  Thanks your valuable support i have tried what you says but no luck it is same issue. so if you don't mind could you please edit my entire code then post it will more help. i would really appreciate.

Comment: @Sajith: It's better that you post a link where I could download your test project with the code. I could fix it and post you URL where you could download the fixed code.

Comment: I am using this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609442/Using-JqGrid-in-ASP-NET

Comment: @Sajith: The referenced article uses ASHX instead of MVC4. Which version of Visual Studio you use? Where is **your** code with the error? Do you have some problem with posting the code? You can send it me per email: oleg.kiriljuk@ok-soft-gmbh.com.

Comment: iam really appreciate you, i am using Visual studio 2012 with entity frame work and mvc4. i cannot fire to controller for the edit action, you can download my project link here( http://we.tl/9gTw47FXx2   )

Comment: @Sajith: You can download updated version [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jQueryGrid.zip). Your main error was missing `return [true]` inside of `beforeSubmit` callbacks. Additionally I make many other small changes like including `.ui-jqgrid table { border-collapse: separate; } .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-input, .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-selbox { width: auto }`, updating `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and `grid.locale-en.js`, modifying the code of `FillGrid` action and some other.

Comment: I have tested what you sent project it is working...nice again Thank You..!!

Comment: Hi @Oleg, Do you know free Nested Jqgrid using MVC with model if you know that please let me know link or Source code.. Thanks your all supports.

Comment: @Sajith: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean under "Nested Jqgrid". Do you want to display [TreeGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid) or [Grid with Subgrids](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid)? jqGrid is **pure JavaScript** library with free open source code. So you can use all features of jqGrid in MVC for free.

Comment: Hi  @Oleg, Trirand.Web.Mvc as whether it is free source or not ? . 

Please see this link http://www.trirand.net/demo/aspnet/mvc/jqgrid/

Can i use this library in my project ?

Comment: @RageshPuthiyedath: It's not free. I don't use it myself. One can implement all using [the free open source jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6).

Comment: @Oleg, is there any Jqgrid with using mvc model binding.

Comment: @Sajith: I don't think that it's really required. One need just be able to provide JSON data from MVC. It's simple enough. jqGrid will be developed as JavaScript (jQuery) plugin. One can debug the code in the source code and makes any fixes if required. So one get maximal flexibility. It's my personal opinion about the subject.

Comment: @Oleg Thank you very much for your valuable reply.

Comment: Hi @Oleg I implement a jQgird free in my mvc4 webapplication. Add, Edit, Delete, operations are works correctly. But my search filter option is not working. there is any additional configuration is needed ?

Comment: @RageshPuthiyedath: It's better if you open new question on the stackoverflow where you describe the current problem in details with source code which you use.

Comment: Ok I will add this as a new question in stackoverflow.

Comment: I add my new question in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751294/jqgrid-search-option-is-not-working Could you please look at this link...